# Fatal Error in wp_get_current_user() Function

Tags: php

When I use below in php code, I have a fatal error. What's happen?
Let me know any reason.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in
```

Comment: it's not clear enough, what php code you use, is it a plugin / theme or outside in another location ? this question may can help you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269174/current-user-wp-get-current-user

Answer (score 3):

You call this function too early, before pluggable function `is_user_logged_in()` is defined. Try this:

```
function wpse_get_current_user() {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  // do other stuff here
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_get_current_user', 10 );
```